# HTML table highlight row on hover except first row (header)

Tags: html, hover, highlight

All,

I have an ASP.NET GridView that is rendered to an HTML table.

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Col 1 Head</th><th>Col 2 Head</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data 3</td><td>Data 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to highlight the row when the mouse is hovered over it - except for the first row which is the header.

I am just getting my head wet with JQuery, and have dabbled a bit with CSS (either CSS2 or CSS3).  Is there a preferred way to do this?

Can anyone give me a starting point for this?

Cheers

Andez

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this using the CSS `:hover` specifier. Here's a demonstration:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Col 1 Head</th><th>Col 2 Head</th></tr>
    <tr class = "notfirst"><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
    <tr class = "notfirst"><td>Data 3</td><td>Data 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.notfirst:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this - css class on each row except for the first one.  Was hoping there was some sort of advanced CSS to do this.  Cheers

Comment: @Andez Actually there is a way to do without specifying a class to each row. Please take a look at my new answer.

Comment: -1, you should be specifying the row *not* to be affected to hover, not specifying *n* number of rows that should.

Comment: @scrowler this was only one of the two solutions I had provided. See second answer.

Comment: @Chris fair enough, I see that. I've +1'd your other answer.

Comment: adding extra class in the markup to all the rows but header is so dirty dirty. far cleaner better solutions below

Comment: @koniu have you looked at [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11902294/364869) I provided?

Comment: @koniu I get what you're saying, but my goal here isn't to be opinionated — just to provide pointers to various solutions. 

As far cleanliness goes, I understand **and agree**. The sad truth is that the state of HTML and CSS standards and implementations currently does *not* support the clear-cut model of separation of concerns that you alluded to (and I'm a big fan of).

Comment: @Chris - I'm not 100% sure what you meant by "The sad truth is that the state of HTML and CSS standards and implementations currently does not support the clear-cut model of separation of concerns that you alluded to" - but doesn't <thead> and <tbody> separate the first row from the rest? [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18210198/1286358). In the OP's question the first row is a header row (<th /> cells)

Comment: Not an ideal way to do it. Far better methods.

Answer (score 83):

There is a way to achieve the desired behavior without class-ing each row separately. Here's how to highlight each table row except for first one (header) on hover using the CSS `:not` and `:first-child` selectors:

```
tr:not(:first-child):hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Unfortunately, IE < 9 does not support `:not`, so to do this in a cross-browser way, you can use something like this:

```
tr:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
tr:first-child:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Basically, the first CSS rule includes **all rows**. To avoid highlighting the first row, you override the its hover style by selecting with `tr:first-child` and then keeping its `background-color` to white (or whatever the non-highlighted row's color is).

I hope that helped, too!

Comment: Thanks, I do like this solution also. +1

Comment: Mind that this won't work where the markup is `<table> <thead><th>foo</th> ... </thead> <tbody> <tr>bar</tr> ... </tbody> </table>`. If that's your markup use - much simpler - `tbody tr:hover` selector.

Comment: That is better answer. Thanks, it works for me very well.

Comment: Doesn't work if you use tables with `<thead></thead>`

Comment: This is better than the answer above it, but the answer below is better yet.  Some day we'll get there :)

Answer (score 55):

To expand on user2458978's answer surely the best way of doing this is to code up the tables correctly.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Then the CSS is simply

```
table tbody tr:hover { background-color: red; }
```

[Here's a jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/U5PQ2/)

Comment: How can I make it by using class name? I added class name -http://jsfiddle.net/bzamfir/2c2jU/ - but now the highlight is no longer working. Thanks for help

Comment: Sorry - might be too late now. The CSS in your Fiddle example is slightly off, .hover table tbody tr:hover { background-color: red; } should just be .hover tbody tr:hover { background-color: red; } as the table is not a child element of the element with the class .hover

Comment: This is the correct way to have a table and thus this is the best answer.

Answer (score 12):

`1.` Place header tr inside thead tag

`2.` Place other tr inside tbody tag

`3.` Use following css

```
table tr:not(thead):hover {
    background-color: #B0E2FF;
}
```

Comment: This did it for me: `table tbody tr:hover { background-color: #B0E2FF; }`

Comment: `:not(thead)` is fine as jQuery selector but neither chromium nor firefox seem too impressed. `table tbody tr:hover` works just fine however - good comment.

Answer (score 3):

Use TH tag for first row and do that:

```
th {
background-color:#fff;
```

}

For all others rows:

```
    tr:not(:first-child):hover {
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

or

```
tr:hover td {
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery to add a class to the parent element of the td (wont select th)

```
$('td').hover(function(){
   $(this).parent().addClass('highlight');
}, function() {
   $(this).parent().removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Then add the CSS class

```
.highlight {
   background:red;
}
```

Comment: From the question it seems like he wants to learn a bit of jQuery that's why I'm using it, personally I wouldn't downvote an answer that would enhance someones knowledge even if you see it as overkill but hey whatever floats your boat.

Comment: I'm gonna +1 that thanks - more information.  Wouldn't say overkill - a useful insight.

Comment: That would be very bad for people to copy paste this in their code. CSS is the proper way to go using `:hover` and `:first-child`. Overkill;

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use

```
tr>td:hover {
/* hover effect */
background-color: lightblue;
}
```

This will only affect table rows with td's inside, not table rows with th's inside. 
Works in all browsers. Cheers, guys.

Comment: This would highlight the single cells, while I think it would be better to highlight the entire row while hovering over any cell of it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like:

```
tr:first-child ~ tr { background-color:#fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As of my requirement, I have to highlight all the even rows except header row.

Hence, this answer might not be suitable to the above question.

Even then, I am giving my answer here with the hope that somebody else can use my answer if they encounter this page in search engine search.

My answer is:

```
$("#tableName tr:even").not("tr:nth(0)").addClass("highlight");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table is standard, you have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>cell</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

so you can use this css code:

```
table > *:not(thead) tr:hover{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```